# Why do I get 'Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.' error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack

I get the error `"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time."` when I run Code A, why?

The Code B can work well when I replace with `fun add(aMVoice: MVoice)=viewModelScope.launch (Dispatchers.IO){}`, why?

The Code C can work well when I replace with  `suspend fun add(aMVoice: MVoice`), why?

And more, which one is better between Code B  and Code C?

**Code A**

```
@Dao
interface DBVoiceDao{
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   fun add(aMVoice: MVoice)
}

class DBVoiceRepository private constructor(private val mDBVoiceDao: DBVoiceDao){ 
    suspend fun add(aMVoice: MVoice){
        mDBVoiceDao.add(aMVoice)
    } 
}

class HomeViewModel(private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : ViewModel() {
    fun add(aMVoice: MVoice)=viewModelScope.launch{
        mDBVoiceRepository.add(aMVoice)
    }
}

class FragmentHome : Fragment() {
    private val mHomeViewModel by lazy {...}
     ...  
     btnInsert.setOnClickListener {     
        val aMVoice = MVoice()
        mHomeViewModel.add(aMVoice)

     }
     ...  
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Dao
interface DBVoiceDao{
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   fun add(aMVoice: MVoice)
}

class DBVoiceRepository private constructor(private val mDBVoiceDao: DBVoiceDao){ 
    suspend fun add(aMVoice: MVoice){
        mDBVoiceDao.add(aMVoice)
    } 
}

class HomeViewModel(private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : ViewModel() {
    fun add(aMVoice: MVoice)=viewModelScope.launch (Dispatchers.IO){    //I add Dispatchers.IO
        mDBVoiceRepository.add(aMVoice)
    }
}


class FragmentHome : Fragment() {
   private val mHomeViewModel by lazy {...}
    ...
    btnInsert.setOnClickListener {     
       val aMVoice = MVoice()
       mHomeViewModel.add(aMVoice)

    }
   ... 
}
```

**Code C**

```
@Dao
interface DBVoiceDao{
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   suspend fun add(aMVoice: MVoice)  //I add suspend 
}

class DBVoiceRepository private constructor(private val mDBVoiceDao: DBVoiceDao){ 
    suspend fun add(aMVoice: MVoice){
        mDBVoiceDao.add(aMVoice)
    } 
}

class HomeViewModel(private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : ViewModel() {
    fun add(aMVoice: MVoice)=viewModelScope.launch {
        mDBVoiceRepository.add(aMVoice)
    }
}


class FragmentHome : Fragment() {
    private val mHomeViewModel by lazy {...}
       ...
       btnInsert.setOnClickListener {     
         val aMVoice = MVoice()
         mHomeViewModel.add(aMVoice)

      }
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Option A uses `viewModelScope.launch`. The default dispatcher for `viewModelScope` is `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#viewmodelscope). As `add` isn't a suspending method, it runs on that dispatcher directly - i.e., it runs on the main thread.

Option B uses `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)` which means the code runs on the IO dispatcher. As this isn't the main thread, it succeeds.

Option C makes `add` a suspending function. As per the [Async queries with Kotlin coroutines guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#kotlin-coroutines), this automatically moves the database access off of the main thread for you, no matter what dispatcher you are using. **Option C is always the right technique to use when using Room + Coroutines**

Comment: need help here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243505/how-to-fetch-edittext-value-from-one-activity-to-recyclerview-of-next-activity#63243505

Comment: Hi , I have a question when i try to declare a method suspend in DAO interface , it even does not compile and gives error. I read somewhere that DAO functions shouldnt be suspend  ? Can please elaborate ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Room doesn't support database access on the main thread unless you've called `allowMainThreadQueries()` on the builder because it might lock the UI for a long period of time. Asynchronous queries—queries that return instances of `LiveData` or `Flowable`—are exempt from this rule because they asynchronously run the query on a background thread when needed.