# How to fetch edittext value from one activity to recyclerview of next activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room, dao

I'm trying to fetch edittext value from one activity and displaying that text in recycleview and storing using room DB....

Basically the idea is adding the address in activity address when clicks on plus it will redirect to next page where the user gets the address form onsubmit it will fetch address and add to previous activity recycleview.

here is my code for room:

table:---

```
@Entity(tableName = "address")
class Address {
@PrimaryKey
var id = 0

@ColumnInfo(name = "address")
var address: String? = null
}
```

Database:-

```
@Database(entities = [Address::class], version = 1)
 abstract class Database : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun AddressDao(): AddressDao
}
```

AddressDao:

```
@Dao
interface AddressDao {
@Insert
suspend fun addData(address: Address)



@Query("select * from address")
fun getAddressesWithChanges() :LiveData<List<Address>>

@Query("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM address WHERE id=:id)")
suspend fun isAddressAdded(id: Int): Int

@Delete
suspend fun delete(address: Address)
}
```

AddAddressActivity activity:

```
   class AddAddressActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.addaddress)

    val editText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.longaddress)

    val application = application as CustomApplication

    saveaddress.setOnClickListener {
        val address = Address()
        address.address = editText.getText().toString()

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            application.addressDao.addData(address)
            finish()
           }
         }
       }
      }
```

AddressActivity:-

```
     class AddressActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
      private val adapter = AddressAdapter()

     private lateinit var data: LiveData<List<Address>>

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.address)

    addbutton.findViewById<View>(R.id.addbutton).setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, AddAddressActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, 
    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    val application = application as CustomApplication
    data = application.database.AddressDao().getAddressesWithChanges()
    data.observe(this, Observer { words1 ->
        // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
        words1?.let { adapter.updateData(it) }})


}
  }
```

AddressAdapter activity:-

```
class AddressAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<AddressAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
private var addresses: List<Address> = Collections.emptyList()

override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, itemViewType: Int): 
   ViewHolder =
  ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
  .inflate(R.layout.address_item, viewGroup, false) )

override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val fl: Address = addresses[position]
    viewHolder.tv.setText(fl.address)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = addresses.size

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var tv: TextView

    init {
        tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ftv_name)
    }    }

fun updateData(addresses:
               List<Address>) {
    this.addresses = addresses
    notifyDataSetChanged() // TODO: use ListAdapter if animations are needed
}
```

}

CustomApplication:

```
class CustomApplication: Application() {
lateinit var database: Database
    private set
lateinit var addressDao: AddressDao
    private set

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    this.database = Room.databaseBuilder<Database>(
        applicationContext,
        Database::class.java, "database"
    ).build()

}
```

}

### list is not displaying recycleview is empty when came back to address activity

please help ..I'm new to kotlin and room db..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> abstract fun AddressDao(): AddressDao?
> ```

Why is this nullable?

> ```
> val favoriteData: List<Table>?
> ```

Why is this nullable?

> ```
> fun addData(favoriteList: Table?)
> ```

Why is this nullable?

> ```
> fun delete(favoriteList: Table?)
> ```

Why is this nullable?

---

Typed nullability is to enable you to represent where a given value ***can*** be null, in the sense that **it makes sense for it to be absent**.

Neither of the above cases represent such a scenario. Room will never return you `null` instead of an actual `dao`.

Kotlin's null safety is to allow you to eliminate potential error cases by making it part of the type system, it shouldn't be used to create "false" error cases such as these. If you're trying to add `null` to a database instead of a real object, you've probably got a bug in your code, and Kotlin should be able to help you eliminate that possibility.

---

---

As for your actual question, you're misusing Room.

`.allowMainThreadQueries()` is a way to disable an error check, but that error is there for a reason. You're not supposed to be reading the data on the UI thread, because with enough data, your app will freeze (ANR).

The code is supposed to look something like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "address")
class Address {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "address")
    var address: String? = null
}
```

Database:-

```
@Database(entities = [Address::class], version = 1)
abstract class Database : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun addressDao(): AddressDao
}
```

AddressDao:

```
@Dao
interface AddressDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun addData(address: Address)

    @Query("select * from address")
    fun getAddressesWithChanges(): LiveData<List<Address>>

    @Query("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM address WHERE id=:id)")
    suspend fun isAddressAdded(id: Int): Int

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(address: Address)
}


class CustomApplication: Application() {
    lateinit var database: Database
        private set
    lateinit var addressDao: AddressDao
        private set
    
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        this.database = Room.databaseBuilder<Database>(
            applicationContext,
            Database::class.java, "database"
        ).build()

        addressDao = database.addressDao()
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:name=".CustomApplication"
    ...
```

Address activity:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.observe

class AddressActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val adapter = AddressAdapter()

    private lateinit var data: LiveData<List<Address>>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.address_activity)
 
        findViewById<View>(R.id.addButton).setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, AddAddressActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        val application = application as CustomApplication
        val addressDao = application.addressDao 

        data = addressDao.getAddressesWithChanges()
        data.observe(this) {
            adapter.updateData(it)
        }
    }
}
```

AddressAdapter:

```
class AddressAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<AddressAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private var addresses: List<Table> = Collections.emptyList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, itemViewType: Int): ViewHolder =
        ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.address_item, viewGroup, false))

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val address = addresses[position]
        viewHolder.tv.setText(address.address)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = addresses.size

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ftv_name)
    }

    fun updateData(addresses: List<Address>) {
        this.addresses = addresses
        notifyDataSetChanged() // TODO: use ListAdapter if animations are needed
    }
}
```

AddAddress activity:-

```
class AddAddressActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.addaddress)

        val editText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.longaddress)

        val application = application as CustomApplication
        val addressDao = application.addressDao
        
        saveaddress.setOnClickListener {
            val address = Address()
            address.address = editText.getText().toString()

            lifecycleScope.launch {
                addressDao.addData(address)
                finish()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can potentially also refer to https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#6

Comment: With the latest Jetpack stuff and the import at the top of that block, both of these should work correctly.

Comment: i dont get it...im using the latest one only

Comment: one error solved...remaining above error are remaing...help @EpicPandaForce

Comment: The IDE tells you the error, and I don't know what it is from over here. If you specify what the IDE tells you when you hover over it, then I might be able to help.

Comment: error at this --> @get:Query("select * from address") saying the anotation is not applicable to target member function and use site target attherateget

Comment: lateinit var database: Database? = null  --)>lateinit error

Comment: Correct, that should no longer be nullable and should not be initialized to null.

Comment: Okay I will try it tomorrow.. But what about the rest two errors? error at this --> @get:Query("select * from address") saying the anotation is not applicable to target member function and use site target attherateget.....error line and red at it--> adapter.updateData(it) in address activity?

Comment: Forgot the `@get:` should just be `@`, but not sure about the `adapter.update` and if you check the error messages in your IDE, it will tell you what is wrong

Comment: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property addressDao has not been initialized

Comment: i have also updated my question code to your code...just cross check if im missing something...error now-->kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property addressDao has not been initialized .........i have also intialized to null but list is still blank...need help

Comment: Well, a line in Application.onCreate(), apparently

Comment: it successfully displayed one row in addressactivity ...when adding next address in Addaddressactivity and submitting it crashes with a error -->     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: address.id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)

Comment: if i do this -->@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) then it is telling to me change version of database...so should i change database version?

Comment: yeah it worked after doing this `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)` and then uninstalling app..thanks a lot

Comment: need help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67182696/compute-the-edittext-value-using-addtextchangedlistener?noredirect=1#comment118752022_67182696

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your line with

```
  val  rv=findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
```

You have passed the wrong id `addressrecyclerview` that's why it was assigning `null`

Comment: Kindly accept this answer and please post a new question, because original exception is now resolved.

Comment: no question is -->how-to-fetch-edittext-value-from-one-activity-to-recyclerview-of-next-activity...help me

Comment: my app is not crashing....but recycleview is empty...please help,..im new to roomdb