# compute the edittext value using addTextChangedListener

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-edittext, addtextchangedlistener

i have a two editext and one textview...textview value is coming from api and based upon the value i have to estimate rest values...

textview value which is coming from api is `tv_UOM_value`
first edittext id is `tv_UOM_0`
second edittext id is `tv_UOM_value_0`

two cases i have to handle:--

1)when i type value in `tv_UOM_0` it should add `tv_UOM_0` + `tv_UOM_value` and display in `tv_UOM_value_0`

2)when i type value in `tv_UOM_value_0` it should subtract `tv_UOM_value_0` - `tv_UOM_value` and display in `tv_UOM_0`

following is my code :-

```
 tv_UOM_0.addTextChangedListener(object:TextWatcher{
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
            if(p0?.isNotEmpty() == true){
                tv_UOM_value_0.setText(
                        "${tv_UOM_value.text.toString()
                                .toInt() + tv_UOM_0.text.toString().toInt()}"
                    )
            }else{
                tv_UOM_value_0.setText("")
            }
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }
        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }
    })
        tv_UOM_value_0.addTextChangedListener(object:TextWatcher{
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                if (p0?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
                        tv_UOM_0.setText(
                                "${tv_UOM_value_0.text.toString()
                                        .toInt() - tv_UOM_value.text.toString().toInt()}"
                        )
                    }
                else{
                    tv_UOM_0.setText("")
                }
            }
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }
            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }
        })
```

above code output:-device gets hang when i type value in first editext

need help thanks in advance...

Comment: You have an infinite loop where changing one text field triggers the callback on the 2nd, which in turn triggers the callback on the 1st and the cycle repeats. You have to break the chain.

Comment: How should I do it @Francesc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that your code is creating infinite loop where both `EditText`s' listeners call each other when value is changed.

There are two ways to handle this scenario:

### 1. Unregistering & re-registering listener (Convenient way)

Let's take an example here:

During listener event of `tv_UOM_0` (first edit text) when you want to change value to `tv_UOM_value_0` (second edit text).

So, before calling

```kotlin
tv_UOM_value_0.setText("${tv_UOM_value.text.toString().toInt() + tv_UOM_0.text.toString().toInt()}")
```

You should remove listener to second edit text using `tv_UOM_value_0.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcherObject for tv_UOM_value_0);` before if/else condition and then after if/else condition re-register listener again.

Same goes for code of second edit text listener.

---

### 2. Check whether EditText has focus (Straightforward way)

During both the listeners you should check whether that given edit text has focus or not and simply return if there's no focus.

Checkout the code below:

```kotlin
// Listener method of tv_UOM_0
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
    if(!tv_UOM_0.hasFocus()) {
        return
    }
    if(p0?.isNotEmpty() == true){
        tv_UOM_value_0.setText("${tv_UOM_value.text.toString().toInt() + tv_UOM_0.text.toString().toInt()}")
    } else {
        tv_UOM_value_0.setText("")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think implementing a `TextWatcher` that would react for a text change on any of two `EditText` fields would help you. This way you would have a full control of what should be modified in which field.

It would a little bit like this:

```kotlin
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if (editable == first_edit_text.getEditableText()) {
        // do other things 
    } else if (editable == second_edit_text.getEditableText()) {
       // do other things 
    }
}
```

Please take a look at the [Android Documentation on TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher)